# Restarting service after changing System Time .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code in my sample program.
Here I am printing the DateTime.Now every 1 second.
Now inbetween if I change the system time to another timezone still the DateTime.Now is taking old value only.
Why is this the case? When I restart the service the new DateTime is reflected. Can someone please explain this? I am changing the timezone of the System manually from Windows Date Time UI while the program is running.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for the timezone is cached: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone.currenttimezone?view=netframework-4.8#notes-to-callers

> Local time zone data is cached after CurrentTimeZone is first used to retrieve time zone information. If the system's local time zone subsequently changes, the CurrentTimeZone property does not reflect this change. If you need to handle time zone changes while your application is running, use the TimeZoneInfo class and call its ClearCachedData() method.